# MaterialTopTabNavigator dynamic route configs

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I want to create via [createBottomTabNavigator](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/bottom-tab-navigator.html). It has 5 tabs. Each tab is a [StackNavigator](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/stack-navigator.html).

One of these tabs has a top tab bar. I create the top tab bar via [createMaterialTopTabNavigator](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/material-top-tab-navigator.html)

But I know tab count after http request. How can I add tab dynamically? The doc says that

> There are workarounds if you absolutely need dynamic routes but you can expect some additional complexity

I am confused about this task.

How can I do that?

Related react-navigation issue: https://react-navigation.canny.io/feature-requests/p/dynamic-routes-for-navigators

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can create a component that returns a tabNavigator. You can then access props or do whatever you want to dynamically add or remove tabs. Here I am using the latest version of react-navigation.

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react-native';

import { createAppContainer, createMaterialTopTabNavigator } from 'react-navigation';

class DynamicTabs extends Component {
  render() {
    // I am using a prop here to update the Tabs but you can use state to update
    // when the network request has succeeded or failed
    const { shouldRenderTab } = this.props;

    const TabNavigator = createMaterialTopTabNavigator({
      Tab1: Tab1Component,
      Tab2: Tab2Component,
      // Create a tab here that will display conditionally
      ...(shouldRenderTab ? { Tab3: Tab3Component } : {}),
    });

    const ContainedTabNavigator = createAppContainer(TabNavigator);

    return <ContainedTabNavigator />;
  }
}

export default DynamicTabs;
```

This is the current solution I am using adapted from the original solution [posted on github](https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/issues/3945#issuecomment-404732749)

Comment: What about the network request isn't ended? Should I wait for it?

Comment: If the data in the tab depends on the request, you should wait, that is the point of the dynamic tabs, is it not? then you can update the prop to render the tab depending on whether the request was successfull or not. I'm curious have you managed to make it dynamic yet.

Comment: But yellowboxes are visible like it says. https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/issues/3945

Comment: I disabled yellow boxes in that project so I never noticed the issue, I also have to check it out now

Comment: I have a follow-up question that I've also asked separately at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58051853/tabnavigator-redux-with-dynamic-route-configs: how do you inject *this.props* values into the above class, and is it possible to use values from a redux store?

Comment: Hi hi, sorry did not check this in a long time, it should be possible to connect this to redux as it is just a component, I havent worked with react native for a while now so maybe now there is a better solution for this, but if you still need it, it should be a simple fix